# How to set textarea value by jQuery and trigger some event just like user input something

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I want to set inputbox value in [Bing Microsoft Translator](https://www.bing.com/translator/)
, I can use:

```
 $('#tta_input').val('something')
```

But translation event are not triggered, it just triggered when I use keyboard input something, so there is any way to trigger translation event when I use `$('#tta_input').val('something')` to change inputbox text?

Comment: so when you set inputbox value? is there any function for it?

Comment: I want to get output content when I set inputbox value

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to trigger the keypress event when the text was changed.
Try the following things -

```
$("#tta_input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var e = $.Event("keypress", {which: 13});
    $(this).trigger(e);
});
```

To check the code:

```
$('#tta_input').on('keypress', function(e){
    console.log(e.which+' -- KeyPress event Fired');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger that function on setting value by `$('#tta_input').val('something')` which you are using for translation on keyboard event.

E.G

```
$("#tta_input").on("keyup", function(e){
    // Your logic of translate
});
```

And when you setting value by `.val()` then you should do this

```
$("#tta_input").val("xyz").trigger('keyup');
```